# Count instances of a text string and output to text file

Tags: powershell

I have a text file which continually updates data from a game.

I would like a script (Powershell) which continually monitors and counts the instances of a text string within this text file and writes the number to another text file or csv. As the instances increase, the script overwrites there previous count with the new count.

Currently I have this

```
  $FileContent = Get-Content "Log.txt"
  $Matches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "Ride On Received" -AllMatches

   $Matches.Matches.Count
```

How do I get this script to continuously monitor for changes and write the count to a text file. It needs to continually overwrite the previous count number.

Thanks

Comment: You are possibly looking for a [file watcher.](https://mcpmag.com/articles/2015/09/24/changes-to-a-folder-using-powershell.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continually is a bit of a rough concept there is arguably no such thing as continually, since processes require time to complete. Instead I'd suggest thinking of it as a script that you want to run repeatedly. Now how often do you really need it to run once a day, an hour, a second, faster?

That being said this should do what you need

```
$CheckFrequency=1000
$filePath="testr.txt"
$countfile="count.txt"

while($true){
    $file = get-item $filePath
    if($file.LastWriteTime -ne $writeTime){
        $FileContent = Get-Content $filePath
        $Matches = Select-String -InputObject $FileContent -Pattern "Ride On Received" -AllMatches
        $Matches.Matches.Count | Out-File $countfile
        $writeTime=$file.LastWriteTime
    }
    start-sleep -Milliseconds $CheckFrequency
}
```

It will check every second or rather every 1000 Milliseconds. If you need it to check even faster reduce the $CheckFrequency variable.

You could reach "Continually" by removing the $CheckFrequency and the start-sleep lines from the script. However your system  may not be happy.